# PHP 7.2 count() Warning

Tags: php

```
$lts = mysqli_fetch_all($con->query($query), MYSQLI_NUM);
for($i=0; $i<count($lts); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($lts[$i]); $j++){
        $lts[$i]=$lts[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

Here is $lts var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '20' (length=2)
  1 => string '21' (length=2)
```

Is giving me this Warning

> Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

This just happened when upgrading from PHP7.1 to 7.2. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure what you are putting into it, is actually an array ;)

Comment: Check that the return of `mysqli_fetch_all()` contains something - could be null for no rows.

Comment: .. and check release notes... they added this warning in 7.2   http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php   "An E_WARNING will now be emitted when attempting to count() non-countable types (this includes the sizeof() alias function)."

Comment: We have to assume the query failed or returned no rows

Comment: @RiggsFolly If it failed, `mysqli_fetch_all()` would complain of a boolean argument. If it returned no rows, `$lts` should be an empty array.

Comment: Going by your edit, you've got an array of strings, not the two-dimensional array that nested for loops would require. So it's the second loop that's returning the error.

Comment: `count($lts[$i])` is the place that raises the warning…

Comment: @iainn `mysqli_fetch_all()` returns a 2-D array. That must be a dump from after the loop is done.

Comment: Yeah, it’s the second count() that throws the error. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first time through the inner loop, you're replacing `$lts[$i]` with `$lts[$i][$j]`. When the loop repeats, it tests `$j < count($lts[$i])`. But `$lts[$i]` is no longer an array, it's the value from the first column of the row, so you get this error.

You can solve this by assigning `count($lts[$i])` to a variable before the loop. But that just raises another problem. When you try to do `$lts[$i] = $lts[$i][$j]` in subsequent iterations, `$lts[$i]` is still not an array, so there's no `$j` element of it.

You can solve that by using `foreach` instead of `for`, since it makes a copy of the array it's looping over.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($lts); $i++){
    foreach ($lts[$i] as $col)
        $lts[$i] = $col;
    }
}
```

But it's not clear what the point of the inner loop is. Each iteration just overwrites `$lts[$i]` with the next column, so the final result will just be the last column. You can do that without the inner loop.

```
foreach ($lts as &$row) {
    $row = end($row);
}
```

or simply:

```
$lts = array_map('end', $lts);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Wordpress 4.9.8 theme installs  (php 7.2 count() Warning) :

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable in
> /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/office/admin/functions/functions.mediauploader.php
> on line 127

## Solution;

line 127 changed...

```
if ( count( $_posts ) ) {
```

to

> if ( is_array( $_posts ) ) {

Answer (score -1):

Create a new function to replace count

```
function count2($x) {
    return is_array($x) ? count($x) : 0;
}
```